# Trying to create a running path for all my images

Tags: java

I am trying to get a running path for the images that are set on my computer. I have set up this path but I have another 30 images that need paths. Do I need to make individual paths for each of the items or can I just have one path that links all of the images.

```
Path p1 = Paths.get("/Users/Matthew/Downloads/download.jpeg");

dLM.addItem("Tomato Soup", "Creamy Tomato Soup served with a warm crusty bread    roll.", 235, 3.90, "/Users/Matthew/Downloads/download.jpeg");
```

Comment: If they are all in the same directory, use `File dir = new File("/Users/Matthew/Downloads"); for(File f : dir.listFiles()) { //... };` (You can also use instead `for(String fileName : dir.list()) { //... }` if you only need the names)

Comment: I have tried to use that code but it is messing with my GUI. Also you have comment out the curly bracket, what is supposed to go in that bracket ?

Comment: Never mind, the code now runs with no errors. I hadn't deleted one of the curly brackets that you had typed out.

Comment: I have to transfer my code from my laptop onto a computer, will the path still exist when I do this, or will I gave to change the path directory.

Comment: Well, that depends if you have the same directory descendant hierarchy in the computer where you are gona execute the program from.

Comment: The code and the directory that I am currently using on my laptop will be different to the directory on the computer. This code is part of my current assignment for University and when I submit this code the lecturer will be using a different computer to read it all. I thought that the path would set the images so that any computer can see the images.

Comment: Then I guess you should add a field or a folder picker where the user can select the directory. With the path from that input, it will be able to work in any computer (remember to check whether the given directory provided by the user exists or not before proceding with the image reading)

Comment: To add a folder picker would I need to create a new class and add the method into that, or do I add the method into the current class where the images are stored.